# Adding Exception to Recurring Appointment Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook

I was successfully able to create a recurring appointment programmatically. Now I would like to enhance it by adding exceptions. I used this site as a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184635.aspx and it would break at `Outlook.Exception myException = newPattern.Exceptions[1];`

When I set a breakpoint and check Exceptions.Count, it's zero if that helps.

```
foreach (var exceptionOccurrence in appointment.RecurrenceRule.Exceptions)
{
    Outlook.AppointmentItem myInstance = outLookPattern.GetOccurrence(exceptionOccurrence.ExceptionDate);
    if (myInstance != null)
    {
        myInstance.Subject = "My Exception";
        myInstance.Save();
        Outlook.RecurrencePattern newPattern = appointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern();

        var myException = newPattern.Exceptions[1];
        if (myException != null)
        {
            Outlook.AppointmentItem myNewInstance = myException.AppointmentItem;
            myNewInstance.Start = exceptionOccurrence.Appointment.Start;
            myNewInstance.End = exceptionOccurrence.Appointment.End;
            myNewInstance.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the particular recurrence instance that you want to modify using `AppointmentItem.GetRecurrencePattern().GetOccurrence()` - it returns `AppointmentItem` corresponding to that occurrence, modify it, and save (`AppointmentItem.Save`).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, any ideas if I want to delete the occurence? Instead of .Save, I did .Delete() but that didn't add an exception.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry, I tried the Save and Delete. It does affect outlook calendar but it doesn't save an exception =(

Comment: What do you mean by "It does affect outlook calendar"? Do you mean you can see the change in Outlook, but Exceptions.Count still == 0?

Comment: Hi Dmitry, exactly I can see the changes in outlook. When I simply run `Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern   = item.GetRecurrencePattern();
                            var test = pattern.Exceptions;` Exceptions.Count is still zero.

Comment: Outlook Object Model is infamous for caching the old stale data for appointments. Do you see the change after you restart Outlook?

Comment: That is so strange. It works now! So after I restarted my machine. It works

Comment: Yep, stale data in OM is a real problem - if you want to avoid that, you'd need to switch to Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or Redemption (any language).